# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"? (5)

Tags: запятые, как

"Дышите, как в лесу" или "Дышите как в лесу"?

Comment: Нужно полное предложение, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос. Постановка запятой перед часто "как" зависит от контекста. Если оборот "как" входит в сказуемое, то запятая не нужна. Но так ли в вашем случае, не определить по вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

***Дышите, как в лесу.***

Оборот "как в лесу" имеет значение уподобления (как будто, словно) и обособляется.

Смысл сообщения не очень ясен, скорее можно ожидать: *дышится, как в лесу*.

А вот пример, когда оборот тесно связан со сказуемым, является обстоятельством образа действия и не обособляется: *ведет себя как лесу* (=слишком свободно, бесцеремонно).